# swift iterate on array

Tags: json, swift, for-loop

i would like to ask a little help.

I have a method which call a webservice and get a json object from it.

it's look like this way:

```
 func wsServiceFeedTst()  {
        println("WS called...")
        println("tstFrames count: " + tstFrames.count.description)

        let json = JSON(url:"http://79.172.249.175:7001/RestWebServiceApp/webresources/entity.bkkkallerfeedtst")

        println(json)

        for (k, v) in json["bkkKallerFeedTst"] {

            let dateShow : NSDate? = v["feedDate"].asDate
            var finalFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            finalFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd - HH:mm"
            let finalDate = finalFormatter.stringFromDate(dateShow!)

            tstFrames.append(TimeFrame(text: v["feedText"].description, date: finalDate, image: nil, routeName: v["feedRouteShName"].description, postId: v["id"].description,routType: v["feedImgType"].description))

        }

    }
```

After i got the json i'm trying to iterate on it and try to add the nodes of the json to another array but when my json contains only one element it's failed because my json is not an array, this is the line where it's throws exception:

```
let finalDate = finalFormatter.stringFromDate(dateShow!)
```

it is waiting for optional, but it get nil caused by this line:

```
let dateShow : NSDate? = v["feedDate"].asDate
```

this is how my json looks like when it has only one element:

```
{"bkkKallerFeedTst":{"feedRouteShName":"143","id":"348","feedLat":"47.5998971180592","feedImgType":"3","feedDate":"2015-06-15T14:07:30+02:00","feedLon":"19.0457082953807","feedText":"Itthon :)”}}
```

And this is how it looks like when it has more then one elements (now it has two element)

```
{"bkkKallerFeedTst":[{"feedRouteShName":"H5","id":"349","feedLat":"47.5535475845461","feedImgType":"2","feedDate":"2015-06-15T15:27:02+02:00","feedLon":"19.0458004338391","feedText":"Hév ;)"},{"feedRouteShName":"143","id":"348","feedLat":"47.5998971180592","feedImgType":"3","feedDate":"2015-06-15T14:07:30+02:00","feedLon":"19.0457082953807","feedText":"Itthon :)"}]}
```

Does anybody has any ide about how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

By the answer i create this:

```
var bkkKallerFeedTst = json["bkkKallerFeedTst"]
var bkkKallerFeedTstArray : [[NSObject : AnyObject]]
bkkKallerFeedTstArray = []
if bkkKallerFeedTst.isDictionary {

    bkkKallerFeedTstArray.append(bkkKallerFeedTst.asDictionary!)
} else {

}

for feed in bkkKallerFeedTstArray {
    println(feed["feedRouteShName"]) //now its printing: Optional(143)

}
```

now it's printing this:

```
[feedImgType: 3, feedRouteShName: 143, feedLat: 47.5998971180592, feedText: Itthon :), feedLon: 19.0457082953807, id: 348, feedDate: 2015-06-15T14:07:30+02:00]
```

UPDATE: this is the solution..

```
 var bkkKallerFeedTst = json["bkkKallerFeedTst"]
        var bkkKallerFeedTstArray : [JSON]

        if bkkKallerFeedTst.isDictionary {
            bkkKallerFeedTstArray = [bkkKallerFeedTst] //initialize
        } else {
            bkkKallerFeedTstArray = bkkKallerFeedTst.asArray!
        }

        for bkk in bkkKallerFeedTstArray {

            let dateShow : NSDate = bkk["feedDate"].asDate!
            var finalFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            finalFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd - HH:mm"
            let finalDate = finalFormatter.stringFromDate(dateShow)

            tstFrames.append(TimeFrame(text: bkk["feedText"].description, date: finalDate, image: nil, routeName: bkk["feedRouteShName"].description, postId: bkk["id"].description,routType: bkk["feedImgType"].description))

        }
```

Comment: Can you state your question in one line?

Comment: my question is how to iterate on my json object if it has only one node..

Comment: The number of key:value pairs doesn't matter with an iteration. So whether it has 1 or 10 it doesn't matter, its the same logic

Comment: Which JSON API are you using? (or what is JSON class a sub class of?)

Comment: By the way, you declare `dateShow :NSDate` as optional, can you verify that it is a valid object? You are unrwrapping it, but its saying its nil. Thats a big hint

Comment: i'm using this api: https://github.com/dankogai/swift-json and if you check my foor loop for (k, v) in json["bkkKallerFeedTst"] { it's try to itareate on an  ["bkkKallerFeedTst"]  but if i have only one line in database this array will not exist.. :(

Comment: What I can tell you is the number of objects in your JSON is not why its failing (nor the number of objects in your array)

Comment: The API allows you to iterate both arrays and dictionary as though they were dictionaries (slightly confusing design imho - but perhaps useful?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be best to define the JSON object initially so it produces an array with a single value, rather than this way, but otherwise you could check to see if you get a valid date, and if you don't try it another way.

But looking at the API you've used, here https://github.com/dankogai/swift-json, it seems you can do checking to see whether you get a dictionary or an array.  So I would cast the dictioanry value to a clearly typed variable for clarity using the '.isDictionary' method.

e.g. something akin to

```
var bkkKallerFeedTst = json["bkkKallerFeedTst"]
var bkkKallerFeedTstArray : [JSON]  

if bkkKallerFeedTst.isDictionary {
    bkkKallerFeedTstArray = [bkkKallerFeedTst] //initialize
} else {
    bkkKallerFeedTstArray = bkkKallerFeedTst.asArray
}
```

May not be this exact code - I don't have the api.

Then you can iterate first through the array (for ? in bkkKallerFeedTstArray), then inside through the dictionary contained (as you were doing before)

Basically make sure you have an array of dictionaries first, before doing the operations.

Example with your code:

```
func wsServiceFeedTst()  {
    println("WS called...")
    println("tstFrames count: " + tstFrames.count.description)

    let json = JSON(url:"http://79.172.249.175:7001/RestWebServiceApp/webresources/entity.bkkkallerfeedtst")

    println(json)

    var bkkKallerFeedTst = json["bkkKallerFeedTst"]
    var bkkKallerFeedTstArray : [JSON]

    if bkkKallerFeedTst.isDictionary {
        bkkKallerFeedTstArray = [bkkKallerFeedTst] //initialize
    } else {
        bkkKallerFeedTstArray = bkkKallerFeedTst.asArray
    }

    for bkk in bkkKallerFeedTstArray {

        let dateShow : NSDate = bkk["feedDate"].asDate!
        var finalFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        finalFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd - HH:mm"
        let finalDate = finalFormatter.stringFromDate(dateShow)

        tstFrames.append(TimeFrame(text: v["feedText"].description, date: finalDate, image: nil, routeName: v["feedRouteShName"].description, postId: v["id"].description,routType: v["feedImgType"].description))

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you but it is doesn't mather i'm trying to get Date or anything.. let dateShow : NSDate? = v["feedDate"].asDate it could be anything else String, etc.. because the array named v doesn't exist.. check the two json in my question.. when i have one line in database, my java backend will create json like this: {"bkkKallerFeedTst":{.... but if database has more then one line my json will be an array: {"bkkKallerFeedTst":[{... and my code is working fine when my json has more lines.. because v array will exist. sorry but i can't describe better my problem.

Comment: I completely understand - the problem you have is when you access json["bkkKallerFeedTst"] - it doesn't know whether it's an array or a dictionary.  You need to make sure it's always an array - so then you can process everything uniformly.  I will try and incoorporate your code into the answer - try it out , there may be mistakes so please feel free to edit them.

Comment: thank you, please check my updated question.. i tried to create what you wrote in your answer..

Comment: with your updated answer it's still throws exception at the same line :( please check my updated question.. :)

Comment: i think i solved with your help.. :) check my updated question. with this:        println(feed["feedRouteShName"]) it's printing Optional(143) now i have to convert it to Sring.. :)

Comment: now i copied your code it has some errors: let dateShow : NSDate = v["feedDate"].asDate! AnyObject does not have a member asDate ... and here bkkKallerFeedTstArray = bkkKallerFeedTst.asArray cannot assign of value of types [JSON] to a value of type [[NSObject : AnyObject ]]

Comment: ok updated - as i dont have the api, you could experiment and then edit the answer if there are a few more typos :)

Comment: Thank you very much! :) i update my question with the solution by your answer! Thank you very much! :)